# Laravel get model with first item from relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have:

```
public function getThumbnail($id) {
    $thumbnail = Product::find($id);
    if($thumbnail) {
        return $thumbnail->with('images')->get();
    } else {
        return response()->json('That cake does not exist.');
    }
}
```

Which returns the product with any images attached it to.

However, I would like it to only return images marked "primary". Something like this (pseudo):

```
return $thumbnail->with('images->isPrimary')->get();
```

How can I achieve this?

---

What about:

```
return $thumbnail->with(['images' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('is_primary', 1);
        }])->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `whereHas` operator in order to obtain all `Products` that have at least one `primary` image, as follows:

```
$thumb = Product::whereHas('images', function ($query) {
    $query->where('primary', 'true');
})->get();
```

More on Querying Relationships [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations).

---

**UPDATE**

After finding your `Product` by `id`, if you just want to show images that are `primary`, you may use [Query Scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes):

In your `Image` class:

```
public function scopePrimaries ($query) {
  return $query->where('is_primary', 1);
}
```

So then you can fetch them like this:

```
$primaryThumbs = $product->images()->primaries()->get();
```

Comment: Keep in mind if a `Product` does not have any thumbnails attached which are primary, this solution will not include that `Product` in the results.

Comment: @JoaquinLRobles What is the difference between your solution and my edit?

Comment: Btw this is bringing back every product with an image, my function takes an $id so I need the find().

Comment: @imperium2335 see my update for more on obtaining just primary images.

Comment: That just brings back the image model data, how do I bring back the product data with it as well?

Comment: why would you do that?

Comment: Because I want the name of the product along with other things, plus the primary thumbnail. If no thumbnail exists, then bring back nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I did this which seems to work:

```
public function getThumbnail($id)
{
    $thumb = Product::find($id);
    if ($thumb) {
        return $thumb->with(['images' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('is_primary', 1);
        }])->whereHas('images', function ($query) {
            $query->where('is_primary', 1);
        })->get();
    } else {
        return response()->json([]);
    }
}
```

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: see my edit using Query Scopes, is the proper way to go!